# Neural network regression with multi-value (probabilistic) functions

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, regression

I'm a bit of a beginner in the art of machine learning. Here is a rather conceptual question I've been wondering:

Suppose I have a function X->Y, say y=x^2, then, generating enough data of X->Y, I can train a neural network to perform regression on the function, and get x^2 with any input x. This is basically also what the Universal Approximation Theorem suggests.

Now, my question is, what if I want the inverse relation, Y->X? In this case, Y is a multi-valued function of X, for instance for X>0, x=+-sqrt(y). I can swap X and Y as input/output data to train the network alright, but for any given y, there should be a random 1/2 - 1/2 chance that x=sqrt(y) and x=-sqrt(y). But of course, if one trains it with min-squared-error, the network wouldn't know this is a multi-value function, and would just follow SGD on the loss function and get x=0, the average value, for any given y.

Therefore, I wonder if there is any way a neural network can model a multi-valued function? For instance, my guess would be 
(1) the neural network can output a collection of, say, the top 2 possible values for X and train it with cross-entropy. The problem is, if X is a vector or even a matrix (like a bit-map image) instead of a number, we don't know how many solutions Y=X has (which could very well be an infinite number, i.e. a continuous range), so a "list" of possible values and probabilities won't work - ideally the neural network should output values randomly and continuously distributed across possible X solutions.
(2) perhaps does this fall into the realm of probabilistic neural networks (PNN)? Does PNN model functions that support a given *probabilistic distribution* (continuous or discrete) of vectors as its output? If so, is it possible to implement PNN with popular frameworks like Tensorflow+Keras?

(Also, note that this is different from a "multivariate" function, which is the case where X,Y could be multi-component vectors, which is still something a traditional network can easily train on. The actual problem in question here is where the output could be a *probabilistic distribution of vectors*, which is something that a simple feed-forward network doesn't capture, since it doesn't have the inherent randomness.)

Thank you for your kind help!

[Image of forward function Y=X^2 (can be easily modeled by network with regression)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J65nH.png)

[Image of inverse function X=+-sqrt(Y) (the network cannot capture the two-value function and outputs the average value X=0 for any Y)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHQVl.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions; please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO.

Comment: Try to use generative models like GAN. The ouput of this nerwork is a random variable following trained distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the following paper:
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/ecjc.1028

Mifflin's algorithm (or its more general version SLQP-GS) mentioned in this paper is available [here](https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/frankecurtis/software/) and corresponding paper with description is [here](http://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/frankecurtis/files/papers/CurtOver12.pdf).